# Cannot switch tabs when in terminal tab

Tags: vimscript, neovim, tabbed-user-interface

For using the terminal while working with Rust. I've added this config (NVIM) (TTerm one).

```
if has('nvim')
    command Ter vsplit term://zsh
    command Tter tabe term://zsh
else
    command Terminal vert term
    command TerminalTab tab ter
endif
```

It opens the terminal in a different tab as expected. Normally with other tabs, we can use the `<C-p>` to navigate to previous tabs. But I cannot use the `<C-p>` or `:tabprevious` as it types it in the terminal. Any options?

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

(This answer pertains to neovim specifically. If you find anything conflicting with vim, let me know and I'll edit the answer.)

`:h term` operates in a separate mode: the terminal model. It's somewhat like the insert mode in that you have to `ESC` out of it before you can go into command-line mode with `:` key. Only to get out of the terminal mode, instead of pressing `ESC`, you press `<C-\><C-N>`. Go through `:h vim-modes` for a complete understanding.

Comment: All of this is true for vim also

Answer (score 2):

1. Control-P by default moves cursor a line up. If it switches tabs instead, then it is due to custom mapping.
2. Vim is all about modes. An "ordinary" buffer may be in Normal or Insert. While in Insert mode, no Normal mappings/keys apply. The same is for a Terminal buffer, except it may be in Normal or Terminal mode. Hence, you need either switch to Normal manually (ctrl-backslash ctrl-n) and then use Normal keys, or create special Terminal mode mapping(s), see help for tmap command and such.

Comment: I beat you by 5 seconds lol

Comment: @kadekai No, it was me faster by 5 sec than you :)

Comment: Thanks for the help. Yeah, actually for the <C-p> it was wrong; what I meant was `ctrl w+p`. Thanks for the help though, `<C-\><C-N>` works!

Answer (score 1):

Using `<C-/><C-N><C-W>r` to get to the split on the right is, IMO, very frustrating. [The neovim manual suggests](https://neovim.io/doc/user/nvim_terminal_emulator.html)  adding "Alt+direction" mappings that would then work from any mode:

```
:tnoremap <A-h> <C-\><C-N><C-w>h
:tnoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-N><C-w>j
:tnoremap <A-k> <C-\><C-N><C-w>k
:tnoremap <A-l> <C-\><C-N><C-w>l
:inoremap <A-h> <C-\><C-N><C-w>h
:inoremap <A-j> <C-\><C-N><C-w>j
:inoremap <A-k> <C-\><C-N><C-w>k
:inoremap <A-l> <C-\><C-N><C-w>l
:nnoremap <A-h> <C-w>h
:nnoremap <A-j> <C-w>j
:nnoremap <A-k> <C-w>k
:nnoremap <A-l> <C-w>l
```

This is what I use personally (except for the insert mode mappings) and I would strongly recommend them. Of course, you would lose any terminal functionality (if any) that was using these mappings.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-). I recommend not to refer to 'Other Answer' since you don't know if there will be not more or if it still exist in the future. Try to make your answer complete and self consistent.

Comment: Yeah this looks good! Thanks

Comment: In Vim, C-w h/j/k/l is all that you need to move left/down/up/right (no C-\ C-n needed).

Answer (score 0):

In nvim, I personally use Ctrl-PageUp and Ctrl-PageDown to switch between tabs, so prefixing Ctrl-\ Ctrl-N to Ctrl-PageUp and Ctrl-PageDown in remap works well:

```
tnoremap <C-PageUp>   <C-\><C-N><C-PageUp>
tnoremap <C-PageDown> <C-\><C-N><C-PageDown>
```